# Applying API changes after checkout from VCS as refactorings (preferably inside the IntelliJ platform)

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea, version-control, automated-refactoring

Are there ways to automaticlly apply changes of an API or library that have been made while in parallel there was ongoing development of the consuming part in another branch for example, just as if one would use a rename or signature refactoring operation in common IDEs, which are usually applied automatically to all consuming parts.

What are the usual strategies to handle these cases as automated as possible when no fully automated tool is used to deal with this.

I'm mainly working with the IntelliJ platform (Pycharm, IDEA), so any possibility directly inside it would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I understand git checkout changes some signatures in the API, and you want IDE to automatically detect the signature change and refactor all its clients in the project? If it is so, it is not possible in the current version.

The best way to handle this, I believe, is to change clients along with the API. This can be achieved by having all the clients in the same project or monitoring API usages via some service.